# Is the 'impossible' room possible?

Tags: blocks-that-matter

I'm playing through the Blocks That Matter demo and there's one bonus level called 'Impossible.' I have four blocks of sand I can arrange in a tetris shape and they're affected by gravity. I can jump 2.5 blocks' height and I need to reach a place that's high seven.

Is this level actually impossible?

Comment: Fun fact: "tetris shapes" actually have [a name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetromino)

Comment: @Dave I know but I didn't feel like digging it up :P

Comment: On the other hand, it's mentioned within the game itself, several times, so you don't really have that as an excuse, either :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Obviously yes, Impossible is possible.

Unlike in Minecraft, sand takes a while before it actually falls down to gravity, so you can just build one tile higher and hurry before the entire contraption falls down.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here's an alternative solution, that uses the same basic idea:

[image]

Start by placing the blocks like this

[image]

As the blocks fall, jump out and back on top of where they're landing.

[image]

This method lets you get a little higher than if you were using the 4th block as a step.

Comment: It's a bit trickier, because if you get squeezed between two sand blocks you _will_ be forced to step down and start over. Kudos for pulling this though!

Comment: @badp - Unfortunately, I can't stand the rest of the game. After playing games like Braid and Toki Tori, which feature a rewind feature, a **puzzle** game who's only recourse is a full-level reset quickly becomes more than tedious. (to me)